# Copy constructor with different struct in c++

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, type-conversion, copy-constructor

How to initialize `ptype2` to copy a `ptype3` struct (type-conversion)?

```cpp
typedef struct PType2 {
    double x, y;

    PType2() : x(0), y(0) {}
    PType2(const PType3 & ptype3) : x(ptype3.x), y(ptype3.y) {} //Abort ptype3.z to create a two-dimensional point
    PType2(double xy) : x(xy), y(xy) {}
    PType2(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
} ptype2;
```

Output:

```
error C2065: 'ptype3' : undeclared identifier
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
error C2228: left of '.a' must have class/struct/union
error C2228: left of '.b' must have class/struct/union
error C2664: 'PType2::PType2(const PType2 &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'ptype3' to 'const int'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I have two `typedef struct`, `ptype2(double x, double y)` and `ptype3(double x, double y, double z)`.

An assignment operator overloading could solve the problem?

Comment: `PType2(const PType3 & ptype3)`  is not copy constructor.

Comment: Was `PType3` defined before `PType2`?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Why do you try to start a comment with `#`? How is `PType3` defined?

Comment: Your code is fine, but the compiler must see the definition of `ptype3` before compiling `ptype2`. You do not need to use `typedef`s for `struct`s in C++ unless you want to give your `struct`s two names. This is different from C.

Comment: `typedef struct PType2` why? Also, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Definition: `typedef struct PType2` and after `typedef struct PType3`. `PType3` is equal to `PType2`, but adds `double z` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can't find PType3. A forward declaration won't suffice here, as you want to access the members of a PType3 in PType2.

You can, however, implement the constructors after defining PType3, then a forward declaration will do the trick.

```
struct PType3;
struct PType2 {
    double x, y;

    PType2() : x(0), y(0) {}
    PType2(const PType3 & ptype3);
    PType2(double xy) : x(xy), y(xy) {}
    PType2(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

struct PType3 {
    double x, y;

    PType3() : x(0), y(0) {}
    PType3(const PType2 & ptype2) : x(ptype2.x), y(ptype2.y) {}
    PType3(double xy) : x(xy), y(xy) {}
    PType3(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};
```

And in the cpp:

```
PType2::PType2(const PType3 & ptype3) : x(ptype3.x), y.(ptype3.y) {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Signature for copy constructor is:

```
T( const&T t );
```

and you do not have it in your code.

If you want to construct `PType2` with  `PType3` you must define`PType3`before `PType2`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `PType2(const PType3 & ptype3)` is not formally called a copy constructor. From C++'s perspective it is `PType2(const PType2 &)`.

I think what you are missing is to include the header file that defines class PType3 .

Having said that the errors you have provided do not exactly match the code. Did you modify code before pasting to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd suggest reading the error messages, but in this case they're a bit confusing. I suppose the problem is that you have not defined `PType3` before `PType2`, it actually has to be fully defined as you try to access members of it (so a simple forward declaration won't do).

The error message seem to arise from a compiler that supports defaulting to `int`. The first error is in that case because the compiler sees `PType3` and since it isn't declared yet it is not a type so the compiler assumes it should default to `int` so it thinks `PType3` is your parameter name. Then it gets confused and also confuses the user (by using non-intuitive ordering of the errors).